# use java script functions that are added to dom after page load (using livewire)

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

i am using laravel with livewire for my website. i am building some kind of wizard containing several steps.

edit: showing whole example
in livewire there is a function called putStepToTwo() that puts $step to 2

```
<div>
@if($step == 1)

   <h1>First step</h1>
   <button type="button" wire:click="putStepToTwo()">Click Me!</button>

@elseif($step == 2)
   <h1>Second step</h1>

   <script>
       function test(){
           console.log("ok");
       }
       document.addEventListener('step2', function () {
            console.log("ok");
       });
   </script>

   <input onchange="test();" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">

@endif
</div>
```

on page load $step is obv. 1. going through the wizard i will reach step 2 and livewire will trigger the render and my step 2 will be shown (there is no page reload).

unfortunately i cannot use the function test -> going to console and typing test(); results in "is not defined". step 2 will contain sliders that will trigger functions (onchange="test();").

and adding the eventlistener doesnt work either. so dispatching an event from livewire doesnt work.

however if i include the script tag in the blade that is used upon pageload, it works.

now in my imagination the js function test is not "registered" ?!? in javascript. therefore i cannot use it.

can i tell javascript or the dom to search for new functions ?

Comment: Is that your entire view? Or is there more to it?

Comment: So when you set the Livewire `$step` to 2, `test` is not defined?

Comment: @Qirel this is only an example. it contains more objects of cours. and the if and endif are covered in <div> and </div> so there is only one root element for livewire. but it show my problem where i want to use java script code thats only included in step 2

Comment: @Yinci yes, imagine there is a button that puts $step to 2  and then there is the render from livewire an then the new step is shown. there the js doesnt work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem with Livewire 3. I solved it as follows:

```
<div>
@if($step == 1)
    <!-- ... -->
@elseif ($step == 2)
    <!-- ... -->
@endif
</div>

@push('js')
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:init', function () {
        Livewire.hook('morph.added', (element) => {
            $(element.el).find('#test').each((index, node) => {
                // Do something with the <input> node or invoke some method.
                test();
            });
        }
    });

    function test() {
       console.log("ok");
    }
</script>
@endpush
```

Make sure that your layout blade contains `@stack('js')` in the body.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some testing and it seems that Livewire does not properly know how to handle HTML tags. Script tags are properly initialized though. What you can do is the following:

```html
@switch($step)
    @case(1)
        <!-- -->
        @break
    @case(2)
        <input id="test">

        <script>
            document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', () => {
                console.log('listener');
                test();
            });

            function test() {
                console.log('test');
            };
        </script>
        @break
@endswitch
```

It is important to define the element before the script, else `getElementById` is null.

Answer (score -1):

DOM is Document Object Model, it is related to your HTML code, it cannot detect new functions.

This happens very often, to fix that you can just put `<script>` tag into `<head>` tag, also this will happen if your javascript syntax is wrong.

Also you can remove the ";" , that may help too:

```html
<input onchange="test()" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
```

One more solution is to make javascript define your function and then execute `window.test = test` before HTML loads (to do this put javascript into head tag)

And then `window.test()` should work like `test()` but correct.

Sorry if something is wrong, I'm newbie in javascript.